# Error while deploying a cluster on openstack

Tags: networking, port, deployment, openstack, pipeline

Error waiting for instance (f6572108-772b-4680-861a-ef3534968616) to become ready: unexpected state 'ERROR', wanted target 'ACTIVE'. last error: %!s()

Comment: Welcome! Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains sufficient details to provide you with a good solution. Only a  *statement*, error message or implied question without a `?` is not enough. Don't only report on client-side issues, also show relevant server configuration & settings, log and/or error messages.  - Please improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.